# Making font size responsive with parent div width and height css

Tags: html, css, font-size

I´m usign font-size: vw;

```
#foti_module_wrapper .tools-nav-option i {
    color: #666666;
    font-size: 6.2vw;
}
#foti_module_wrapper .tool-nav-label {
    font-size: 3.2vw;
    line-height: 4px;
}
#foti_module_wrapper .tool-item {
    -webkit-box-flex: 1;
    -webkit-flex: 1 0 auto;
    -ms-flex: 1 0 auto;
    flex: 1 0 auto;
    display: flex;
    text-align: center;
}
#foti_module_wrapper .tools-nav-option {
    -webkit-box-flex: 1;
    -webkit-flex: 1 0 auto;
    -ms-flex: 1 0 auto;
    flex: 1 0 auto;
    padding: 10px;
    color: #292929;
    font-size: 20px;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: inherit;
    cursor: pointer;
    border: 0;
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    -moz-appearance: none;
    appearance: none;
    z-index: 2;
    background: white;
}
```

In mobile works fine, but in tablet the font icon and text overflow my tool-item padding...

I want to avoid this

[image]
[image]

I want this result:
[image]

Comment: well you could easily use media queries to write code for tablets

Comment: I do not want to use media queries

Comment: the only way without media queries is js! is there a reason to not use media queries - cause its exactly what its made for...

Comment: Have you try to use % in font-size?

Answer (score 0):

```
#foti_module_wrapper .tool-nav-label {
    font-size: 3.2vw;
    line-height: 4px;
}
```

You can use font-size: 3.0vh, if you want it to be responsive with height also.    Vw and Vh are for width and height responsive respectively.